# Google Apps Script e.namedValues format multiple choice

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a simple script that emails the results of a Google Drive form submission. One of the questions in the form has multiple choice checkboxes. I am using e.namedValues to grab the array of answers so that I can email them, like this:

```
var multiple = e.namedValues['Multiple Choice Question'].toString();
```

And the result that gets emailed is this:

```
Answer 1, Answer 2, Answer 3
```

But I would like the result to be formatted like this:

```
Answer 1
Answer 2
Answer 3
```

Instead of separated by commas. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JavaScript String's split function

```
var multiple = e.namedValues['Multiple Choice Question'].toString();
var choicesSelected = multiple.split(',');
multiple =''; 
for(var i in choicesSelected){
  multiple += choicesSelected[i] + '\n' ;
}
for (var i in multiple){
  Logger.log(multiple[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! However, I get this error: Missing ; before statement. (line 13). Line 13 is the "multiple += choicesSelected + '\n' l" line. I removed the l, and it didn't give me the error message, but then instead of taking out the comma separation, it lists the choices 5 times with comma separation. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo. Fixed it. If you split it across multiple Logger.log statements, you should see it on multiple lines. See edited example

Comment: I really appreciate your help on this. But, I still think something is wrong. Instead of listing each answer once and with a line break, I am getting this output: "Answer 1, Answer 2, Answer 3, Answer 1, Answer 2, Answer 3, Answer 1, Answer 2, Answer 3, Answer 1, Answer 2, Answer 3, Answer 1, Answer 2, Answer 3, " - with no line breaks at all, just duplicated answers with comma separation. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function myFunction(e) {
   var eMails = e.namedValues['Your question here'].toString();
   var choicesSelected = eMails.split(', ');

   /**
      eMails =''; 
      for(var i in choicesSelected){
      eMails += choicesSelected[i] + '\n';
   }

   */
   for (var i in choicesSelected){
      Logger.log(choicesSelected[i]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Provide some explanation about the code example.