# script for converting Google Forms checkbox results into individual line items

Tags: forms, google-apps-script

I have a google form that I use to log the clients that I see each day.  At the end of the day I go to the form, check the boxes next to the clients that I have seen, and that gets logged in a spread sheet.

For easy reporting, I am trying to take the comma deliniated responses that the checkbox option gives and copy them into a new sheet with each reponse on a new line

I am at a bit of a loss as to how to go about it.  I am new to java and still getting the hang of it.  My first thought was to getRespnce and put it into an array that I could for loop.  but I really have no idea how to do that  :)

I found one answer here [How to split and transpose results over 2 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530499/how-to-split-and-transpose-results-over-2-columns/35203775#35203775) though I am running into trouble with that code.

Ideally I would have something that would run on form submit, take the answers from the first item, and log them line by line in a new sheet

Any help would be amazing.

Thanks!

(This is mostly a challenge that I gave myself to help learn how to code in app scripts.  I have done a lot of work trying to figure it out but I realize that it is beyond my scope at the moment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more research and found the answer that I was looking for with the e.namedValues()

the helpful post:  [Google Apps Script e.namedValues format multiple choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12733634/google-apps-script-e-namedvalues-format-multiple-choice)